# Root for the underdogs or Root for the underdog

Tags: plural-forms, singular

She likes to root for the **underdogs**

She likes to root for the **underdog**

I'm confused to decide which form to use here, plural or singular !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, **underdog** is used as a general term for a player or team that is not expected to win. It is not specific as is.

So I think one would generally say:

> She likes to root for the underdog.

As for

> She likes to root for (the) underdogs.

this may not be technically wrong, but it sounds odd and I don't think it is what anyone would say.

Comment: I'm glad you put the article in parenthesis. I agree that _She likes to root for underdogs_ works better than the version that includes a definite article, as you have hinted in your answer.